# ng-repeat shows one row before rendering rows from the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a back end service which sends data to a `$scope` variable. I am using this variable to populate rows in a table using `ng-repeat`.

When the page is loaded, one row is displayed on the browser and it suddenly disappears when the page loading is complete. In a while, when my data is retrieved, the required rows are populated as expected.

I want to remove that first row as it doesn't look good.

Below is the code:

```
...
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <td ng-bind="row.vname"></td>
    <td ng-bind="row.mname"></td>
    <td ng-bind="row.time_start"></td>
    <td ng-bind="row.time_end"></td>
    <td ng-if="row.progress!='-1'">
        <p class="btn-info btn-rounded" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;"> Complete</p>
    </td>
    <td ng-if="row.progress=='-1'">
        <p class="btn-danger btn-rounded" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;"> Failed</p>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
...
```

The row which is displayed in the beginning displays the two rounded buttons with text "complete" and "failed".

Comment: make sure your `$scope.rows = []` when the app just loads

Comment: @manish `$scope.rows` is initialized in the function which is rendering data from the backend. The blank row is not displaying data from `$scope.rows`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The row you see is a row built before angularjs initialization.

You need [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) to hide it.

ng-cloak will hide it until angular is up and running.

Like this :

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows" class="ng-cloak">
    <td ng-bind="row.vname"></td>
    <td ng-bind="row.mname"></td>
    <td ng-bind="row.time_start"></td>
    <td ng-bind="row.time_end"></td>
    <td ng-if="row.progress!='-1'">
        <p class="btn-info btn-rounded" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;"> Complete</p>
    </td>
    <td ng-if="row.progress=='-1'">
        <p class="btn-danger btn-rounded" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;"> Failed</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Sometimes the [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) blocks the capability of angularjs to add the `ng-cloak` class. In this case you need to add it in your css like this :

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Adding `class="ng-cloak"` to `tr` is not solving the problem. The blank row is still being displayed.

Comment: Be sure you have the coresponding css class in your css. `[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}` sometimes you have to add it yourself.

Comment: Worked. You can add this to your answer too.

Comment: Nice. I just added it.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion is adding the attribute ng-if="row" on tr tag

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows" ng-if="row">
...
```